# How do I fetch only the last entry from a table

Tags: php, mysql

i have a messages page, and i need to only get the last message from each user, my database is the following: msg_id, message, userid, toid, datecreated
its for a php chat, i just need the last message from each user

im getting the results this way

```
 <?php
 $sqlmessages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE toid=$logid");

 while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlmessages))
 {

 $aid = $_POST ['m_id'];
 $message = $runrows ['message'];
 $userid = $runrows ['uid'];
 $toid = $runrows ['toid'];
 $date = $runrows ['datecreated'];


 ?>            

 <?php echo $message;?>


 <?php } ?>
```

i need to change the sql to just get the last message from database, any ideas?

Comment: Try to use `mysqli_*` functions instead of `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: did you try to use limit? **SELECT * FROM message WHERE toid='..' ORDER BY datecreated DESC LIMIT 1**

Comment: Have you solved the problem? Take my answer into consideration

Comment: NO, i still cannot solve it

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$sqlmessages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE toid=$logid ORDER BY msg_id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

**EDIT**

then do it like this :

```
$sqlmessages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE toid=$logid GROUP BY(userid) ORDER BY msg_id DESC");
```

Comment: but that wont work, it will show me only 1 message, if i have multiple messages from multiple users, i just want to see the last from each one, with that query i will only see 1 message ONLY, thanks eitherway

Answer (score 0):

try this: I assuming `$userid` is your user's field

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE toid=$logid GROUP BY $userid ORDER BY $date DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['$userid']. " - $". $row['$message'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: you should seriously consider shifting to PDO. mysql is depreciated in php 5.5 so your code will not run when your host provider upgrades to php 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Thinking in sets:

```
SELECT
    u.user_name,
    u.uid,
    m.m_id,
    m.toid,
    m.datecreated
FROM
    users u
LEFT JOIN
    /* auxilary table to create set of uid with max m_id*/
    (SELECT
        uid,
        MAX(m_id) max_id
    FROM
        messages
    GROUP BY uid
    ) a
    ON u.uid = a.m_id
LEFT JOIN
    /* now join the messages again to get the latest message */
    messages m
    ON a.uid = m.uid AND a.m_id = m.m_id
```

If only users with messages are required change LEFT in INNER join